# 98 Grand Cherokee drains battery

Tags: electrical, battery, jeep

The battery would go dead after sitting for a day. I checked battery and found a bad cell with a hydrometer. Replaced the battery and the problem remained. I hooked my meter between the positive post and the cable. It showed 6 amps, and I pulled all fuses in the kick panel, one at a time - none of these stopped the draw. I unhooked the rear door and glass sensor, to no avail. I unhooked the black connector to the controller on the firewall, on the passenger side, and the draw stopped. I ohmed all pins in the connector and found nothing. I plugged it back in and the draw remained gone for a few days. Checked again and it was drawing 4 amps. I unhooked the alternator and it was still drawing 4 amps. I have added a negative disconnect temporarily, until iI find the problem. I tried unhooking the black connector for the controller again, but this time it did not stop the draw. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There should be a fuse box under your hood and under the passenger side dash. You should go back to square one and check the draw as you remove each individual fuse one by one. If you've removed every fuse and still find a draw or a dead battery, then you've really got a mystery on your hands. In that case, a positive wire somewhere has been exposed and is grounding out.

Also, I would remove the high and low fan relay just in case.

Comment: the jeep is a limited and has a information center. it shows a problem with the rear lights, but there really is not a problem back there. i was checking the draw again two days ago and it was not there. it must come and go.

Answer (score -1):

Known design fault , the security alarm drains the battery ALL THE TIME.

I am not qualified , i am passing on information from my best friend, he bought this vehicle from new and spent three miserable years before jeep owned up to the fault.
good luck , great car shitty security system.